# Excel keeps changing date format from custom format to default

Tags: excel

I keep putting a custom format as follows: yyyy-mm-dd
But if i save the file and reopen it goes back to dd-mm-yyyy

It works fine in xlsx, but i need it in csv and if i try converting it from xlsx to csv, same thing happens

Comment: A CSV is a text file. If you open it in Excel, Excel will interpret the text as dates and apply its default date format, but the actual csv file data will be stored in whatever format it was when you saved it in Excel. Why does it matter what Excel does to it when opened?

Comment: Because when i import the csv it comes in an undesired format.

Comment: Import it to where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no style or format settings for CSV file. A CSV file is simply a text seperated by comma or an another delimiter. If you opened up the CSV file in notepad or notepad++ you can see the dates are correctly formatted.

If you want to retain settings, you can try saving it an XML file.

When you open a CSV file directly in Excel, Excel determines the format of the cell based on its interpretation of the text, which is similar to its interpretation of data that enter manually.

Most of the time, the cell format is General. In some cases, it is Short Date, Time, Accounting or Percentage.

Also note that the date or time appearance in the CSV file should be consistent with the Regional and Language Options settings on the computer where the CSV file is opened.  Otherwise, Excel interprets it as text.

If you import the file instead of opening it directly, you can control how Excel interprets the data via setting format settings for dates upon import.